# How to connect Genymotion to Android Studio version 3.5.3?

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, genymotion

I am using Android Studio version 3.5.3, when I connect to genymotion.

1. file, settings, plugin
2. No browse repositories item found?
3. Can't get browse repositories

My question is about Android Studio Version 3.5.3. I can't get the browser repositories to add genymotion to the latest Android Studio version.

Answer (score 0):

Abbas,

You just need to search for genymotion in the marketplace section.
Here is the path to search **File->Settings->plugins->Marketplace and search for genymotion**[image: Image for genymotion]

Answer (score 0):

To install genymotion plugin : 
Go to **File --> Settings --> Plugin --> Look up Genymotion keyword --> install it**

PS : click Apply and then a pop up message will ask you to restart android studio

[image]

**Step 2 : Connect your genymotion with android studio 
Go To  **File --> Settings --> other Settings --> Genymotion and browse to your genymotion directory and click apply**

[image]